# How to query when one ID has more than one name and find the total count of unique names, id

Tags: mysql-5.6

Same id having more than one name and the count of the unique names which are associated with the unique id

[image]

Comment: Have you even tried anything???

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT id, name) `count`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP
```

If you do not need in total count, it's simplified to:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT name) `count`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY id
```